# Episerver Scheduled Jobs- Manual trigger identification

Tags: scheduled-tasks, jobs, episerver

I'm trying to find whether the Episerver Scheduled job (Episerver CMS 11) is triggered manually or automatically.

While on finding in Episerver documents I do see the 'ScheduledJobTrigger' and 'ScheduledJobLogItem' are related to this. But still, I am unable to find out how to call the service for implementation and get the expected value. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Update: ScheduledJobLogItem.Trigger is having expected the values (Unknown,Scheduler,User and Restart). User will Indicates that the job was started manually by a user from the Administration. But am always having the value 'Unknown' for both Manual/Automatic trigger

Comment: Hint: when manually running a scheduled job, there is a current user. When run automatically, there's no current user. Why do you need to know, is it for the execution or for looking at logs?

Answer (score 0):

In code, the `ScheduledJob` will not have a user associated with it's context when fired automatically (either via `API` or scheduled firing), whereas a manual start *will* have user context associated to it.

If you are looking to identify if this was triggered manually, checking that user context *may* be what you are looking for.